# Help explaining steps in a solution (involving trig functions and algebra)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I was reading a textbook and was trouble deriving a particular equation. The last step involved this
[image]

Can anyone explain why letting the constant be $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ leads to the final answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what all of the $\frac{l^2}{\mu k}$ and such represent, but I can tell you that $\sin(x - \frac{\pi}{2}) = -\cos(x)$ since sin & cos are the same function with one horizontally shifted.  Not sure if that helps.  Perhaps the earlier part of the problem will help shed more light on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the numerator and denominator were both multiplied by $\dfrac{\ell^2}{2\mu k}$. Note that inside the square root, this becomes $\dfrac{\ell^4}{4 \mu^2 k^2}$. So that makes the RHS $$\large \dfrac{-\frac{\ell^2}{\mu k}\frac 1 r + 1}{\sqrt{1 + \frac{2E\ell^2}{\mu k^2}}}.$$

Now, $\sin(\frac \pi 2 - \theta) = \cos \theta$, so $\sin(\theta - \frac \pi 2) = - \cos \theta$. This gives the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
\cos{\theta}&=\sin{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)}\\
&=-\sin{(\theta-\frac{\pi}{2})}\\
&=-\frac{-\frac{2}{r}+\frac{2\mu k}{l^2}}{\sqrt{\left[\frac{2\mu k}{l^2}\right]^2+8\frac{\mu E}{l^2}}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{2}{r}-\frac{2\mu k}{l^2}}{\sqrt{\left[\frac{2\mu k}{l^2}\right]^2+8\frac{\mu E}{l^2}}}\cdot\frac{\frac{l^2}{2\mu k}}{\frac{l^2}{2\mu k}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{l^2}{\mu k}\frac{1}{r}-1}{\sqrt{1+2\frac{E l^2}{\mu k^2}}}
\end{align*}